# Chrome Extension - Detect Status Code of Page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, http-status-codes, content-script

I have a content script which manipulates a webpage. If the webpage doesn't load (maybe the server gives you an error 500, or chrome can't connect) I want it to retry and refresh the page after a minute or two.

Content scripts aren't injected into the page if chrome can't connect to load the page. Not sure about error 500s, but I know you can't simply detect the status code from within a content script.

How can I, regardless of if the page successfully loads, detect a non-200 status code of a page? I understand that I'll probably have to do this outside of a content script, I'm not sure where I need to do it though.